# Developing NodeJS application locally, run in Docker container, no reload, volume issue

Tags: node.js, docker

Plan:

1. Have my code developed locally on host machine Windows 10
2. Mount volume with that code into the container
3. Run node in a container via nodemon which will reload itself i update my code on host machine
4. Have my node_modules installed during image build phase and copy that into the app folder during container run phase

**TL;DR**

The problem is that when I NPM install during image build phase and then I run the container with my custom image with the volume path which is the same as WORKDIR - it wipes out package.json and node_modules that I have installed during image build, because obviously it replaces the content of the container with host machine's mount folder.

Host machine folder structure:

`C:\Project\Dockerfile
C:\Project\src\ - code here`

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:8

WORKDIR /app

COPY src/package.json /tmp
RUN cd /tmp && npm install
RUN mkdir -p /app && cp -R /tmp/node_modules /app/

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

So far all good. Now all I need is to add a volume during docker run and "combine" existing content of /app and the one that will be on my host machine.

How to do that?

Will fail:
`docker run -p 8080:3000 -v C:\Project\src:/app -d deb0rian/host
maker_test`

And there's no way to relocate node_modules into another folder, nor mount my src in /app/src since node_modules will be one level lower now and it won't be discovered by require function for example.

Couldn't find a solution on the internet, everyone seem COPYing the src into the container, and that's bad for development speed.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: I don't think you can "combine" the content from the host with the content on the docker container. Usually, the content from the host is copied into the container. 
Since package.json is inside Project\src, doesn't that mean your node_modules also inside Project\src? If so, then you can try changing your -v flag to only mount the relevant code instead of the whole src folder (something like -v C:\Project\src\code:/app)

Comment: I ended up putting my code in a nested folder called "code" just like you said, and that is my volume to the host, just specify in package.json `  "main": "code/server.js"` and node will be able to resolve modules from a nested folder, same applies to all paths used in run scripts. All is good now :)

Comment: Glad to hear you got it working!